# Raspberry Pi Zero g_mass_storage not recognized by some Systems

Tags: usb, pi-zero, gadget

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W configured as a USB device (latest raspian version 5.10.11+).
[Make a Pi Zero W Smart USB flash drive](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive)

In general it works fine, and the device will be recognized by Windows 10, other Raspberry Pi's, Mac OSX.

However, I work on a project with a special Touch Screen devices where the configured Zero W is not recognize in the running Application, while other simple USB Sticks are!

It is recognized on the "OS level" but not within the application - which can not be debugged nor changed. However, the USB Stick is recognized fine.

So as it is still not recognized, I followed [Change Raspberry Pi Zero USB Gadget name from Linux File-Stor Gadget](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107010/change-raspberry-pi-zero-usb-gadget-name-from-linux-file-stor-gadget) and tried to configured it like a working KINGSTON USB Stick. This also worked fine on Windows, Linux, .. but still same situation - not recognized on the target device/application.

lsusb -v shows almost the same output compared to a HW USB Stick that was recognized.

**Zero W device - not recognized**

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 102/2.0 / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0930 Toshiba Corp.
  idProduct          0x6545 Kingston DataTraveler 102/2.0 / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick
  bcdDevice            1.10
  iManufacturer           1
  iProduct                2
  iSerial                 3
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0020
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              5
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

**Recognized USB Stick**

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x090c Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.)
  idProduct          0x1000 Flash Drive
  bcdDevice           11.00
  iManufacturer           1
  iProduct                2
  iSerial                 3
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0020
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval             255
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval             255
```

**However, Windows SDK USB Device Viewer shows the following for the mass storage**

```
[Port2]  :  USB Mass Storage Device


Is Port User Connectable:         no
Is Port Debug Capable:            no
Companion Port Number:            0
Companion Hub Symbolic Link Name: 
Protocols Supported:
 USB 1.1:                         yes
 USB 2.0:                         yes
 USB 3.0:                         no

Device Power State:               PowerDeviceD0

       ---===>Device Information<===---
English product name: "DataTraveler"

ConnectionStatus:                  
Current Config Value:              0x01  -> Device Bus Speed: High (is not SuperSpeed or higher capable)
Device Address:                    0x34
Open Pipes:                           2

          ===>Device Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x12
bDescriptorType:                   0x01
bcdUSB:                          0x0200
bDeviceClass:                      0x00  -> This is an Interface Class Defined Device
bDeviceSubClass:                   0x00
bDeviceProtocol:                   0x00
bMaxPacketSize0:                   0x40 = (64) Bytes
idVendor:                        0x0930 = Toshiba Corporation
idProduct:                       0x6545
bcdDevice:                       0x0110
iManufacturer:                     0x01
     English (United States)  "Kingston"
     German (Standard)  "Kingston"
iProduct:                          0x02
     English (United States)  "DataTraveler"
     German (Standard)  "DataTraveler"
iSerialNumber:                     0x03
     English (United States)  "94B86DC69273E36020005166"
     German (Standard)  "94B86DC69273E36020005166"
bNumConfigurations:                0x01

          ---===>Open Pipes<===---

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x81  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 1
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0200 = 0x200 max bytes
bInterval:                         0x00

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x01  -> Direction: OUT - EndpointID: 1
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0200 = 0x200 max bytes
bInterval:                         0x01

       ---===>Full Configuration Descriptor<===---

          ===>Configuration Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x09
bDescriptorType:                   0x02
wTotalLength:                    0x0020  -> Validated
bNumInterfaces:                    0x01
bConfigurationValue:               0x01
iConfiguration:                    0x04
     English (United States)  "0"
     German (Standard)  "1"
bmAttributes:                      0x80  -> Bus Powered
MaxPower:                          0x32 = 100 mA

          ===>Interface Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x09
bDescriptorType:                   0x04
bInterfaceNumber:                  0x00
bAlternateSetting:                 0x00
bNumEndpoints:                     0x02
bInterfaceClass:                   0x08  -> This is a Mass Storage USB Device Interface Class
bInterfaceSubClass:                0x06
bInterfaceProtocol:                0x50
iInterface:                        0x05
     English (United States)  "Mass Storage"

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x81  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 1
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0200 = 0x200 max bytes
bInterval:                         0x00

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x01  -> Direction: OUT - EndpointID: 1
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0200 = 0x200 max bytes
bInterval:                         0x01
```

**While the working USB Stick looks like the following:**

```
[Port1]  :  USB Mass Storage Device


Is Port User Connectable:         yes
Is Port Debug Capable:            no
Companion Port Number:            1
Companion Hub Symbolic Link Name: USB#VID_05E3&PID_0612#5&17c61b84&0&17#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8}
Protocols Supported:
 USB 1.1:                         yes
 USB 2.0:                         yes
 USB 3.0:                         no

Device Power State:               PowerDeviceD0

       ---===>Device Information<===---
English product name: "USB Flash Disk"

ConnectionStatus:                  
Current Config Value:              0x01  -> Device Bus Speed: High (is not SuperSpeed or higher capable)
Device Address:                    0x35
Open Pipes:                           2

          ===>Device Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x12
bDescriptorType:                   0x01
bcdUSB:                          0x0200
bDeviceClass:                      0x00  -> This is an Interface Class Defined Device
bDeviceSubClass:                   0x00
bDeviceProtocol:                   0x00
bMaxPacketSize0:                   0x40 = (64) Bytes
idVendor:                        0x090C = Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan
idProduct:                       0x1000
bcdDevice:                       0x1100
iManufacturer:                     0x01
     English (United States)  "General"
iProduct:                          0x02
     English (United States)  "USB Flash Disk"
iSerialNumber:                     0x03
     English (United States)  "04XGF0375YV9FNX3"
bNumConfigurations:                0x01

          ---===>Open Pipes<===---

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x81  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 1
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0200 = 0x200 max bytes
bInterval:                         0xFF

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x02  -> Direction: OUT - EndpointID: 2
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0200 = 0x200 max bytes
bInterval:                         0xFF

       ---===>Full Configuration Descriptor<===---

          ===>Configuration Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x09
bDescriptorType:                   0x02
wTotalLength:                    0x0020  -> Validated
bNumInterfaces:                    0x01
bConfigurationValue:               0x01
iConfiguration:                    0x00
bmAttributes:                      0x80  -> Bus Powered
MaxPower:                          0xFA = 500 mA

          ===>Interface Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x09
bDescriptorType:                   0x04
bInterfaceNumber:                  0x00
bAlternateSetting:                 0x00
bNumEndpoints:                     0x02
bInterfaceClass:                   0x08  -> This is a Mass Storage USB Device Interface Class
bInterfaceSubClass:                0x06
bInterfaceProtocol:                0x50
iInterface:                        0x00

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x81  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 1
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0200 = 0x200 max bytes
bInterval:                         0xFF

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x02  -> Direction: OUT - EndpointID: 2
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0200 = 0x200 max bytes
bInterval:                         0xFF
```

**So the main difference seems to me that No Symbolic Link Name was generate, and "Is Port User Connectable" are set by the working USB stick.**
However, I have no clue how this is set and why.

```
Port1]  :  USB Mass Storage Device


Is Port User Connectable:         yes
Is Port Debug Capable:            no
Companion Port Number:            1
Companion Hub Symbolic Link Name: USB#VID_05E3&PID_0612#5&17c61b84&0&17#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8}
```

Many thanks up front for your thoughts!

Comment: Interesting problem, however, technically speaking, the issue is with the "target application" not working with drives which don't have a partition table. That's not specific to Raspberry Pi in any way: you can just as well remove all partitions from a thumb drive and I bet it will also stop working.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue why it was not recognized.
Problem was the image file. It did not contain a partition.

I found this in the message file of another rasperry pi when I connected the it, and compared it with the messages from the working stick.

It showed **"sda:"** only and not **"sda: sda1"** as with the working one.

```
Feb 17 11:14:59 raspberrypi kernel: [57675.026460] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
Feb 17 11:15:00 raspberrypi kernel: [57675.127408] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5572, bcdDevice= 1.1a
Feb 17 11:15:00 raspberrypi kernel: [57675.127416] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
Feb 17 11:15:00 raspberrypi kernel: [57675.127421] usb 1-1.3: Product: Cruzer Switch
Feb 17 11:15:00 raspberrypi kernel: [57675.127425] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
Feb 17 11:15:00 raspberrypi kernel: [57675.127430] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 1234567890
Feb 17 11:15:00 raspberrypi kernel: [57675.129371] usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 17 11:15:00 raspberrypi kernel: [57675.129656] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
Feb 17 11:15:00 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 27: "/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Feb 17 11:15:00 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 27 was not an MTP device
Feb 17 11:15:00 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 27: "/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Feb 17 11:15:00 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 27 was not an MTP device
Feb 17 11:15:01 raspberrypi kernel: [57676.155130] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Linux    File-Stor Gadget 0510 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Feb 17 11:15:01 raspberrypi kernel: [57676.155434] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Feb 17 11:15:01 raspberrypi kernel: [57676.158811] sd 0:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
Feb 17 11:15:01 raspberrypi kernel: [57676.159728] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4194304 512-byte logical blocks: (2.15 GB/2.00 GiB)
Feb 17 11:15:01 raspberrypi kernel: [57676.159956] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Feb 17 11:15:01 raspberrypi kernel: [57676.160495] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Feb 17 11:15:01 raspberrypi kernel: [57676.184522]  sda:
Feb 17 11:15:01 raspberrypi kernel: [57676.187085] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
Feb 17 11:15:16 raspberrypi kernel: [57691.847168] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 27
Feb 17 11:15:16 raspberrypi kernel: [57691.849264] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Feb 17 11:15:16 raspberrypi kernel: [57691.849505] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
```

So i followed the steps to generate the image file from [USB Gadget: Mass Storage Emulation](https://forum-raspberrypi.de/forum/thread/36132-usb-gadget-mass-storage-emulation/) which generates a partition within the storage file.

And now it is recognized also by the application.